# My Azure API Management Service connects to a serverless HTTPTrigger, but a matter of hours later, it stops working and returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am using the API management service to manage my API.  When I initially setup the:

i) API - pointing to an Azure Function App with a HTTPTrigger
ii) Product - using the API
iii) Subscription - created by the product

Initially it works fine.  I can query it manually from curl a command like:

`curl -X GET "https://mydomain.io/foo/v1/get-my-data?input_value=3" -H Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <KEY>`

But after a few hours (<12) all of a sudden it starts failing, and returns a 401.  It fails not only from the command line, but even from within the API Azure console using the "Test" tool - see screenshot

[image: API test tool]

`< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

I haven't change anything, it just starts occurring.
I can fix the problem by:

1. Removing the Subscription
2. Removing the Product
3. Remove the API
4. Adding back the API
5. Adding back the Product with a Subscription

I am new to using the API management service.

Reading through many of the Azure troubleshooting docs I have checked:

- There is not rate limiting set on my subscription
- The subscription key is correct
- Changing the subscription key alone doesn't fix the problem, only recreating the API fixes it

The fact that the test tool is not working makes me think it's something to do with the handshake between the API and the serverless HTTPTrigger not playing nicely.  But I really don't know how to fix or figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code in Azure.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
public  static  async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, string customerName, ILogger log)
{

log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
string name = customerName;
string requestBody = await  new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
name = name ?? data?.name;
string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.": $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

return  new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

Serverless Az-Function with Http Trigger

[image]

Code snippet

[image]

Response

[image]

Using Azure function URL

[image]

- And created an API management and linked the above-mentioned Customer function to the API management without any issues.

[image]

- Check the settings as mentioned below.

[image]

- And also, while creating the API management check the valid details.

[image]

For more information, refer to the [Errors with API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/troubleshoot-response-timeout-and-errors) and [Azure API Management.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/diagnose-solve-problems)

Comment: Thanks - I had setup all of my Azure API very similar to above.  The problem isn't getting it working.  It is that after a short while (approx 6 hours or so) the communication between the API Management layer and the underlying backend service fails due to 401 unauthorized error.  Please help?

Comment: The issue you are facing could be due to authentication and authorization issues between the API Management layer and the underlying backend service.

In Azure API Management, a backend is an HTTP service that implements your front-end API and its operations. It is the service that your API Management instance forwards requests to. The backend can be an HTTP-triggered Azure Function App.

Comment: Check if the backend service is configured to require authentication and authorization. If it is, you need to configure API Management to authenticate and authorize requests to the backend service. You can use OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure AD to protect access to your API in Azure API Management.